# Adding image in simplenews template file

Tags: 7, emails

I am using [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module with [htmlmail](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail). I am trying to add an image in template file `htmlmail--simplenews.tpl.php` Below is my code:

```
<?php global $base_url; ?>
<div class='contentEditableContainer contentImageEditable'>
  <div class='contentEditable'>
    <a target='_blank' href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $base_url.'/'.drupal_get_path('theme','my_theme').'/logo.png';?>" alt="Logo" width='60' height='60' data-default="placeholder" data-max-width="200"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this I am not able to get the image in outlook and gmail. I even tried setting img src as base64 but didn't work out. Please help.

Comment: Images will no be displayed if you sent the newsletter from your local environment

Comment: Thanks but It's not on my local environment.